# "Error in native callback" using ffi-napi in electron and electron-builder

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ffi

I have a simple electron app, trying to use `ffi-napi` to call a dll file, but I'm getting an "Error in native callback" when running the electron build. Here is my setup:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "electron-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps",
    "dist": "electron-builder"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^23.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^23.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ffi-napi": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "electron-test",
    "win": {
      "target": "portable"
    },
    "asar": false
  }
}
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const ffi = require('ffi-napi');

const createWindow = () => {
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
    })

    win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})
```

and **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'" />
    <title>Hello from Electron renderer!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello from Electron renderer!</h1>
    <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```

I ran these in order:

1. `npm i` which installs the modules and runs build script on the `ffi-napi` package
2. `npm run start`

And received this error:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: Error in native callback
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1259:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1044:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1068:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at load (C:\workspace\temp\node_modules\node-gyp-build\node-gyp-build.js:22:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\workspace\temp\node_modules\ref-napi\lib\ref.js:8:53)
```

I'm not sure how to solve this, any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @guowy, I'm getting the same error...

Comment: I ended up using the koffi module and it worked wonders.

Comment: Thanks guowy.
I've switched to koffi and added nodeIntegration: true to BrowserWindow and was able to upgrade electron from 19.x to 20.x finally !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a BUG/FEATURE in Electron after 20.3.8 version.
The team added a sandbox and anything that tries to read from memory using pointers (i.e. `ref-napi` that has been used by `ffi-napi`) will crash electron.

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/35801
https://www.electronjs.org/blog/v8-memory-cage

for now, it seems that the only solution is to keep using `20.3.8` version until this discussion will be over.

a workaround can be to use a fork of `ffi-napi` and `ref-napi`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwahonen/ffi-napi https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lwahonen/ref-napi

as discussed here:
https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/238#issuecomment-1461642322

but  it seems we'll have to wait until electron team will fix this issue or will create an official workaround.

Comment: Another work around is to use the Koffi NPM package

Comment: i switched to Koffi, a well maintained project

Answer (score 4):

I'm not very good at English, so there may be some awkward phrases, please bear with me.

I also encountered the same problem, and I searched for many solutions and reinstalled electron many times. Finally, I changed the version of electron to 20.0.0 (this is a version I tried randomly). It seems that I can finally run electron when adding ffi-napi.

The syntax I used is `npm install electron@20.0.0`.

I hope this helps and wish you success!

Comment: Thank you, I did get it working with older version, but unfortunately I need the newer version of electron.