# Electron uncaught error: Error in native callback node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle when npm start

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ffi

I have an electron application running in ubuntu20.04 but when doing npm start, it throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error in native callback
    at process.func [as dlopen] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1354:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1822)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:965:12)
    at f._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13330)
    at o._load (node:electron/js2c/renderer_init:2:3109)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1148:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at load (/home/raulgimenez/De…-gyp-build.js:22:10)
```

I am using node version 16, npm version 9.8 and libraries as ffi-napi. Does anybody know what is happening?

Thank you in advance,
R.

Answer (score 0):

What electron version do you use? I struggle with the same error after updating electron from 20.3.8 to 20.3.9.

Electron had been adapted and doesn't support external buffers anymore, see [changelog](https://releases.electronjs.org/release/v20.3.9):

*"Added node-api: handle no support for external buffers."*

I found more struggling people over here:

https://github.com/node-ffi-napi/node-ffi-napi/issues/238

Apparently, it helped some to use another fork since the original ref-napi/ffi-napi repository seems to be vacated.

The alternative forks can be installed like this:

```
npm i @breush/ref-napi
npm i @breush/ffi-napi
```

Also related to ["Error in native callback" using ffi-napi in electron and electron-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75668307/error-in-native-callback-using-ffi-napi-in-electron-and-electron-builder/75978712#75978712)

Good luck!